# Looking for a plaintext list of swear words

Tags: text

Not sure if this is really a programming question, but here goes :-)

I'm playing around with a wordsearch generator and it occurred to me that if I'm actually going to let anyone use it, it would probably be a good idea to make sure that the randomly-generated filler text doesn't contain rude words. Is there a standard list of words out there that I could use?

Comment: serverfault might be a good place for this as I'm sure lots of admins try to keep those words out of emails, etc.

Comment: @David or maybe use some original ones when someone break things.

Comment: I'm sure the users here could generate one for you fairly quickly...

Comment: Google "George Carlin" and "dirty words".

Comment: Yeah, I tried searching but the lists that came up were mostly intended for censoring forums etc. which is kind of a different use case.  Hopefully my script is not going to try to get round the censor by 'randomly' generating the string 'm0th£r4uck3r'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick google search and came up with this:

http://support.discusware.com/center/resources/tips/cusswords.html

Comment: Thanks, looks perfect (well, I know that by its nature this type of thing can never be perfect, but you know what I mean).

Comment: Out of date link unfortunately